# Git reset --hard head (revert) not updating Symbolic Link targets in Windows

Tags: windows, git

I created a symbolic link in Windows 7 to a version controlled file called xyz.txt like this:

```
mklink /H ..\xyz.txt xyz.txt
```

The destination of the symbolic link is not part of the git working copy, and is not version controlled (I have also tried the scenario where the target is part of the working copy hierachy, and in the *.gitignore* and experience the same problem).

When I change the contents of the file on either side of the symbolic link, it works fine.

However, when I revert the file (for example using `git reset --hard HEAD`), the target of the symbolic link doesn't update to the unmodified version of the file, as I would expect.

What explains this behavior, and how can I work around it?

Comment: I suspect that something about git reset breaks the symbolic links. If it deletes the source file and then re-adds it, that would do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by replacing

```
 mklink /H ..\xyz.txt xyz.txt
```

with  `mklink ..\xyz.txt ..\xyz.txt`

Replacing hardlinks with standard symbolic links got the revert functionality to work properly. An important gotcha is to notice that standard symbolic links (without `/H`) need to have the `source` parameter path be relative to the `destination` path, otherwise the link won't work.